# Continually monitor on-prem databases for changes and update AWS databases

Tags: amazon-web-services, sql-server, database, migration, replication

We have several servers hosted on-prem that are older systems.

I want to use Data Migration Service(or any other AWS tool) to monitor the older SQL Server 2008 instance (just a few tables, not the entire DB) for changes.

I then want to update databases(doesn't matter which kind) being stored in AWS with the changes after applying schema conversion rules (possibly joins, etc).

This process should continue forever.

Right now the task can be done, but with custom made, RESTFUL services. This is not ideal.

I'm sure other businesses are attempting to do the same thing, so is it possible to use DMS to accomplish this? or any other AWS services?

Answer (score 0):

[Database migration service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Introduction.html) would do this - it says on the front page of the documentation

A typical task consists of three major phases:

- The full load of existing data
- The application of cached changes
- Ongoing replication

[AWS Data Pipeline](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-copydata-mysql.html) is another option. It's an older service, I think DMS is better.

If neither of those options work for you, you could also consider:

- Native database replication
- Something with Lambda that queries the old database regularly and insert in the new database, but that will be custom.